# JPA - "No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111" when calling a postgresql function with varchar

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am getting this exception when trying to call a postgresql function thru the JPA api. I've seen the following error when using unknown types, but this is String / Varchar.

Any ideas?

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
```

Java code:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("log.uf_remove_fks")
                                          .registerStoredProcedureParameter("_schema", String.class,
                                                                            ParameterMode.IN)
                                          .setParameter("_schema", schema);
query.execute();
```

Postgresql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log.uf_remove_fks(_schema VARCHAR(10))
    RETURNS VOID
AS $$
     DECLARE rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    ...
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Stack Trace:

[image: Stack Trace]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems Hibernate is not happy about the function returning VOID, so changing it to return INT and just calling RETURN 1 at the end solved the problem.

Comment: is this the final answer? are there no any better solutions with function returning nothing?

Comment: never found any other solution